# How to insert wait step in Splunk Synthetics (formerly Rigor) API test

Tags: splunk

Trying to program in a wait step within Splunk Synthetics (Rigor) API test.

Use case: Submitting a test file to an API endpoint and takes 10 seconds to process file.  Successfully being able to submit this file is the test criteria to pass/fail on.  Response body from endpoint includes status but need to program in a wait step or a while loop.  Splunk Synthetics does not have a wait step natively in API mode.  Anyone ever done this via a saved JS file or script?

If status="processing" then loop
OR
If status ="in progress" wait 15 sec and check again
THEN
If status= "complete" then pass; if status= "failed" then fail.

Comment: what have you tried? What error(s) have you gotten?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Splunk Support, right now you cannot.  There is a work around to call out to an external site able to pause for a set time to occupy the bots time then make a call back to get status.  I added a request to the IdeaBoard for future implementation.  Just putting this answer here for anyone else that looks for it.